# How to fix missing fonts problem in debian (parrot os)

Tags: linux, fonts, fontconfig, parrotsec

I have a problem with my Parrot OS machine that is using KDE.

[image: My problem]

This is GIMP an image editing software. But like you see it misses some fonts so it displays these strange characters. GIMP is not the only software that is doing this. I tried a lot of things but nothing worked.

### UPDATE

When running GIMP from the terminal I get this error: Gtk-Message:

```
17:21:52.735: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
```

And also this error:

```
(gimp:69440): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:21:52.743: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
```

### UPDATE

If I go to font management, in the system fonts tab
You will see that every font package has these rectangles in them.

[image: Fonts]

I guess that's the thing  that is causing these problems.
So I guess that my fonts are probably corrupted or I installed a font the wrong way.
But, how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have any error running GIMP (or another software with the same font issue) from the terminal?

Comment: Maybe helpful https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uniform_look_for_Qt_and_GTK_applications

Comment: I get this error: Gtk-Message: 17:21:52.735: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
And also this error: (gimp:69440): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:21:52.743: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

Comment: I'm not familiar with Parrot OS, but if it works like most Debian based Linux dists you  should open "Language Support" and check if your language is properly installed. Or use the command `check-language-support`to get a list of missing packages and install them with `apt install`

Comment: I tried, it is not working.

Comment: Hmmm..., In any case you should install `libatk-bridge` and `gtk-engines-murrine`and all their dependencies and then see what happens in terms of errors. Possibly the whole `murrine-themes`

Comment: I installed all packages. When I run GIMP from the terminal there are no errors. But it still displays these strange characters.

Answer (score 1):

I found what the missing fonts are. If you have the same problems like me
just execute these two commands:

```
apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
sudo dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig-config
```

I hope I helped

Comment: Congratulations!